# Odd behaviour with UITableViewCell when scrolling, UIButtons disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to set up some UIButtons and UILabels in my custom UITableViewCell. For each row in the table I have 4 buttons with user profile images and below each button is a label displaying the username. Images and usernames are taken from Parse.com. I have a friends array of size 34, and I am displaying 9 rows so the last two buttons and label must be hidden. The code below works but for some reason when I scroll up the table some of the other rows will also hide their two rightmost buttons and labels. I'm wondering if my logic for loading images from the array is incorrect. Not sure what's going on here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FriendViewCell *cell = (FriendViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ((int)indexPath.row * 4 + i < [self.currentUser.friends count]) {
            UIButton *button = cell.buttons[i];

            [button setTag:(int)indexPath.row * 4 + i];
            button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2;
            button.clipsToBounds = YES;
            UILabel *label = cell.labels[i];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(friendTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            //here we need to decide what to access
            PFUser *user = self.currentUser.friends[(int)indexPath.row * 4 + i];
            label.text = user.username;
            PFFile *userImageFile = user[@"profilePic"];
            [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock: ^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            UIButton *button = cell.buttons[i];
            [button setEnabled:NO];
            [button setHidden:YES];
            UILabel *label = cell.labels[i];
            [label setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh answer should fix most of your issues. Something that a lot of people overlook is that in a table view cells are reused. So anything you change will remain if not changed again. Almost always it is a simple matter of doing the opposite in an if else.

Comment: why is this the case just for the buttons I am trying to hide? If cells are being reused then won't some of the profile pictures also be reused so you end up having users with the same profile pictures?

Comment: That is correct. If you turned off your hide logic in the else you would notice that the profile images are being reused, however because when you decide to unhide them you set the image you don't notice. Also you may want to think about setting the image to a placeholder image because your getDataInBackgroundWithBlock: may take a while and you don't want to see the old image also hopefully setting the image is on the main thread. That is all off subject though. Glad it is working for you now.

Comment: Oh I get it, the cell creation line either creates a fresh cell or reuses one in the reuse queue. If you get a fresh cell then everything will work okay but if it's a cell for reuse we are getting back that same cell. I was always changing the profile picture and username so that was fine, however if that cell comes back with hidden buttons it will still be hidden unless I unhide it first. Got it. I was wondering about what would happen with slow images and just tested it, it was using old images while waiting for the new ones. I will set placeholder images as soon as the cell is created. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by unhiding the button and Label in your first conduction like:

```
if ((int)indexPath.row * 4 + i < [self.currentUser.friends count]) {
     [button setEnabled:YES];
     [button setHidden:NO];
     [label setHidden:NO];
     // Other code
}
else{
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'iOS' way to handle this would be to fill out the prepareForReuse method of your custom cell.  This is where you should be reseting various attributes on cells that may be reused by the caching system.

### [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)

**-prepareForReuse**

Prepares a reusable cell for reuse by the table view's delegate.

**Discussion**

If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.